# Hash based data container that can be fragmented - C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, hash, record

I would like to index a series of singular values or struct/classes ( meaning more than 1 value hashed at a time ) based on their hashing.

I have coded the hashing function, so no problem for providing the digest for any value or struct or classes, the problem is:

- there is a real support for hash based data structure in C++ ? I mean if there is a better alternative to a trivial use of `std::map` for example, and a **container designed for this**  with more than 2 fields ( I still haven't decided how many fields I really need in my data structure ) .
- since i plan to easily reach the 10^5 records, managing a **fragmented data structure** it's important for me to avoid dealing directly with a giant data structure in memory and allocate useless parts of the structure.
- if I would like to **save this structure on disk**, the serialization is the only option ?

Suppose that my hash function is `hash::digest()` I will appreciate a minimal reference to actual code with an example about the usage of an appropriate data structure.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I would like to avoid unordered data-structures because:

- bad branch prediction
- since they are not ordered they can't be fractioned in an effective way
- my main focusion is about the management of this structure and its fragmentation.

Comment: Have you looked at `unordered_map`?

Comment: @KeithRandall I would like to avoid unordered data structures

Comment: Why?  I mean, what about `unordered_map` is insufficient?

Comment: @KeithRandall ordered data structures offer a better branch prediction, i can pay for a slightly longer "insert time" because my structure is mainly used for a search. Also this should be mixed with the possibility to fragment this data structure and if it's unordered I can't really fragment this structure in an effective way.

Comment: What sort of system is this supposed to run on? Even simpler mobile phones should have no issue whatsoever to have 100000 elements, in any of the ordinary storage containers (std::map being the most suitable for). 

It's not quite clear what you mean by "more than 1 value hashed at a time" - do you mean like a multi-indexed system for first name, last name, telephone number and shoe-size, so you can search by any of those?

Comment: @MatsPetersson I should not have write that, with "more values" i mean the member of class being hashed, but since my hashing function is in charge of returning the digest, this doesn't matter for the data structure itself.

Comment: I don't understand. If you have a single hash function that combines all fields into one number, how can you use this for field-specific searches?

Comment: @jogojapan because the key is the hash, the other fields can be just names, numbers, POD ...

Comment: I disagree with both of your premises, that `unordered_map` has bad branch prediction, and that you can't easily fragment an `unordered_map`.  `unordered_map` at reasonably low load factor branch predicts well (and even if it didn't, a branch miss isn't that expensive) and it's trivial to fragment an `unordered_map` - just split the elements by a function of the hash.  For instance, to split the table 10 ways, just compute h(x)%10 and put each element in the resulting indexed portion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to write this as an answer, because I don't think commenting is really getting us anywhere:

First, I think that you are either barking up the wrong tree, or you need to sit down and draw a little diagram for us, so we understand what you are asking.

In general, I, and many others, follow the principle of "use std::vector when it's works (indexing is reasonable type/range), until proven that it's not good enough. If indices don't work for vector, use std::map, unless proven that this is not a suitable solution". But more importantly, whatever storage you use, should be hidden from the main code. You should have accessor functions to fetch the data, and it shouldn't matter if you use a vector, map, trie, B-tree, heap, stack, queue, etc. As long as the functionality your program needs can be supplied by your interface, it should be possible to store the data in any sort of container class. With this principle, you can change your actual storage container when/as you need, without having to worry about whether the code using the container will break or not.

As to storing the data structure, anything that isn't just POD will need to be serialized, whatever form of container you are using. So if you store any class, e.g. std::string, then you MUST serialize the data, because the internal structures can't just be stored in a file.

Comment: +1. I would add that it should be unkknown to the rest of the app whether the data is stored in memory(vector, map etc...) Or in a Database.

Comment: honestly i was looking at serialization as a "general approach" to this problem, meaning that you can serialize almost everything that can be represented in bits and bytes, from images to data types, so i was looking for and hoping for a more specific solution for custom data-types.

Comment: Of course you can serialize things, but how does that relate to containers that you are asking about?

Answer (score 1):

In your description you state that you want something using a a "hashing" function (sometimes referred to as "digest") which seems to indicate that you want to use some sort of hashed container. Hashed containers are inherently unordered but you also state you don't want to use an unordered container like the standard libraries `std::unordered_map<...>`. What is it that you want with your hashing function?

You also state that you want your container to be "fragmented" but I'm quite unclear what you mean with this fragmentation. From the sounds of it you seem to imply that you container is actually partially held on disk and only brought in memory as due to its size. Note, however, that 10^5 is not a *huge* size but, actually, a fairly tiny size!

If you mean that your "hashing" function actually provides an order, i.e., it provides a [strict weak order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strict_weak_ordering) on the keys, and your content can be presented as a sequence of bytes (e.g., using appropriate serialization and deserialization), you might be looking for a [b-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree): A data structure based on data segments. Although I'm sure that there are C++ implementations of this data structure there isn't one in the standard C++ library. Nor do I have code available and it isn't entirely trivial to create b-tree.

Comment: so, going straight to the point: you are suggesting the serialization as a solution ?

Comment: If your data sets are indeed too large to fit into memory, you'll end up with some sort of database where a layman's version would be some order with some form of serializing the data. For many data sets there is no need to even bother because the system's memory management system will take care of paging data to and from disk as needed.

Comment: the main and real problem it's not that it's too large for the memory, i don't want to load something in memory that i'm not going to use. Imagine to load the entire phone book for the entire City when you are looking for only the numbers that respect a specific pattern. Fragmenting data can be useful to apply some custom pattern to ehance the data management.